# How do I stop the MATE GUI?

Tags: gui, mate, ubuntu-mate

I installed the MATE GUI on my server so that I could use remote desktop to test some things. It worked fine, but I don't want it it running all the time. It just bothers me to have [all of these unnecessary processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gdXz.png) running when I don't need them 99.9% of the time (and possibly never will again).

How do I disable MATE without uninstalling it? Preferably keep it disabled until I want it (i.e. not start on system startup).

Comment: @MarkKirby that doesn't cover MATE

Comment: It is nothing to do with MATE, it is xorg and grub that is the same on any ubuntu.